# How to parse different number types with LALR(1)

Tags: parsing

Consider a LALR(1) parser for a file format that allows integer numbers and floating point numbers.

As usual, something like `42` shall be a valid integer and a valid float (with some automagic conversion in the background).

There might be parsing rules where a floating point number or an integer number is expected, and other rules where *only* an integer number is expected, e.g.:

```
foo1
    : bar FLOAT buzz
    | bar INT buzz
    ;

foo2
    :  some INT other stuff
    ;
```

Now consider something like

```
foo3
    : bar FLOAT xyz FLOAT abc FLOAT buzz
    ;
```

but at each position in this rule, instead of `FLOAT`, also `INT` shall be allowed.

- Turning this rule into 8 rules (one rule for each combination of `FLOAT` and `INT`) isn’t an option. (Consider a rule having 4 or 5 numbers...)
- Using a rule like

  ```
  float_or_int : FLOAT | INT;
  ```

  won’t help, because in general, this rule will reduce all `INT` to `float_or_int`, and rules like `foo2` no longer can be parsed. (Because with a grammar large enough, the one token lookahead cannot avoid the shift-reduce-conflicts resulting from this rule.)
- When the lexer sees a number without a decimal point, it cannot decide whether the parser currently expects an int or a float-or-int.

How can this be handled in an elegant way?

Comment: Could you present a practical example of the issue you are fearing with *float_or_int : FLOAT | INT* ?  I've used that in the past without meeting them in practice and in the artificial examples I can build, the ambiguity is fundamental.

Comment: @AProgrammer Take the `foo1` and `foo2` rules from above, add a `main : foo1 | foo2;`, and add rules `bar : INT;`, `buzz : INT;` etc. That’s of course (very) artificial, but in my actual project, which is larger and which I definitely cannot post here, such a rule will create a lot of shift-reduce conflicts. And I already had the same with at least two other parsers. It (of course) depends on the tokens that can follow `INT` or `FLOAT`, and if you design a language from scratch, you can take that into account. But when parsing some existing stuff, I made the experience there will be conflicts.

Comment: @AProgrammer The point is that I’d really like to use a `float_or_int` rule, but the file format to be parsed doesn’t allow it and I cannot change the file format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is typically done is that the numeric constant is "parsed" in the lexer, with "number type" (int, float, base, ...) information made available to the parser.  You use the simple int_or_float rules in the grammar, and then the associated semantic actions are responsible for verifying that you have legal number types in each place, and declaring an error if you don't.

The parser will apparently succeed in parsing the file, but you will still have flagged the errors, and you can refuse to generate the result based on those errors.

Comment: That is, one single token for all number types?